# Kiosk application launching another application

Tags: windows, kiosk-mode

I need to implement an update feature for an app that runs in Windows kiosk mode. During an update, the app must close in order to replace its executable, Since closing the app also shuts down Windows, I thought to have a second executable (launcher.exe) which launched my application and never closed. However when I put the second executable in kiosk mode it isn't able to start my app. Can an executable in kiosk mode launch another process?

Comment: Maybe you can make your application a DLL then launcher.exe just needs to unload the DLL, replace it then re-load it.